# MySQL group by is including null rows

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a query that is using a calendar table to get me the number of orders per day for the month. This includes the denomination of the product ordered and its total sum issued.

```
SELECT
    reward.denomination,
    SUM(CASE WHEN dateCreated IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as totalRewards,
    SUM(reward.denomination) as totalIssued
FROM
    calendar as c
LEFT JOIN reward
   ON DAY(reward.dateCreated) = c.cday
   AND MONTH(reward.dateCreated) = c.cmonth
   AND YEAR(reward.dateCreated) = c.cyear
   AND reward.userID = 1
WHERE
    c.cmonth = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
AND 
    c.cyear = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
AND
    c.cday <= DAY(CURRENT_DATE())
 GROUP BY reward.denomination
 ORDER BY reward.denomination ASC
```

[image]

In this output, the first row is showing `0` for total rewards and then `null` for the other two columns.

However, there are only 4 records in total that this should be dealing with (which are correctly shown in the result set.

Why is this first row being included and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: it's probably caused by `left join`, does the user get rewarded **_every single day_** ?

Comment: Ah shoot, that was it :/ - No the rewards can be any time throughout the month. That looks like it fixed it :x

Comment: Your description of what the query does is quite different from what the query actually does.

Answer (score 0):

Your `left join` is keeping all rows in `calendar`.  For any rows that don't match, the columns from `rewards` are kept . . . but the columns  are `NULL`.  Such a row would be a date where user 1 does not have a reward.

Your aggregation key is on `rewards`, so the key is `NULL` for the non-matches.

SQL is doing exactly what it is supposed to be doing.  You probably just want an `inner join`.

I think your query would be simpler without the `calendar` table at all:

```
SELECT r.denomination, COUNT(*) as totalRewards,
       SUM(r.denomination) as totalIssued
FROM reward r
WHERE r.userID = 1 AND
      r.dateCreated <= CURRENT_DATE() AND
      r.dateCreated >= CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL (1 - DAY(CURRENT_DATE()) DAY
GROUP BY r.denomination
ORDER BY r.denomination ASC;
```

In addition to simplifying the query, this allows you to use simpler date arithmetic.  As a bonus, this can take advantage of an index on `rewards(userId, dateCreated)`.